# Measuring distance of values / strings

Tags: string

martin fownler was discussing event sourcing

https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html

e.g. storing data as a set of events.

Now an example would be an account. You create an account with balance 0.

Then you put 10$. You withdraw 5$. You put another 100$. Now the balance is 105$, but you don't store 105$. What you do store is

```
+10
-5
+100
```

as a series of events in the database.

Now if I want I can say "undo the last 2 steps." then I just remove the 2 last changes in the database -> account is `10`

Now: how can you do that with strings?

Say account name first is empty string. Then
`dirk dietmeier` then `hans hansenmann` then `foo bar` how can you capture this data as set of changes? While letting it be reversable e.g. the events need to be able to reverse itself. E.g. you could just say 'delete everything and then put `foo bar` but is there no better solution?

is there like a svn or git like algorithm? some encoding (hex, binary?)?

Comment: Why the git and svn tags?

Comment: @Julian because git and svn both measure very well distances of strings. Dont you think so? their system is well proven and state of art. Maybe that's how once should implement it? e.g. git diff light.

Comment: Look up *edit distance* or *Levenshtein distance*, or start with the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)

Comment: @torek interesting. But looking at it, i guess that's the reason git didn't implement it. It looks very very expensive to do that for bigger chunks of text

Comment: I think it's confusing to include tags for tools that has implemented algorithms you like to use. It's not a git or svn question, so I removed them to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> Now if I want I can say "undo the last 2 steps." then I just remove
>   the 2 last changes in the database -> account is 10

**Not if you want to preserve the history**. In production event sourced applications, I would **issue a compensating event**. E.g. New event Y that undoes what event X did. The git analogue to this would be `git revert`.

> Now: how can you do that with strings?

It **depends on your application**.

1. **If you are tracking changes to code**, it makes sense to do some research on how to express differences between two files, such that you can revert at a later time. In this sense, your **event would be similar to a git commit**. I suggest you look at the diff linux command http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/diff1.html and look at the source code, or how you can implement it.
2. **If your event is something like** `CustomerFirstNameChanged`, doing a diff makes very little sense. You would always want to revert to a previous state such as `John` or `Rick`.

Number 2 would also make sense with an event such as `ArticleRedrafted`, where you can go back to a previous version. Content editors don't see revisions as we see git commits when we use `git revert`... They see them as points in time that can be returned to.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could represent the change from one string to another string as a reversible operation.  It really would depend on requirements.

I would not expect the deltification in a source control system to necessarily meet the general needs you've outlined above.  For example, git's purpose in deltifying files for storage (which it only does when generating a pack) is to save space.  Older versions of an object may be stored as deltas from newer versions, but there is never a need to reconstruct the newer version via delta from the older version - it's stored in its entirety specifically so that it can be accessed quickly (without need to combine deltas).  So storing enough information for the delta to be used as a two-way transformation would be wasteful from git's point of view.

Instead of looking at the pack deltas, you could think about how `diff` represents a change.  This is more line-oriented than you seem to want.  If you have an edited file, you might represent the edits as

```
d37
- Line 37 used to contain this text, but it was removed
a42
+ We added this text on line 42
c99
- Line 99 used to have this text
+ Line 99 now has this text
```

You could do a character-oriented version of this.  Say you define operators for "add characters at offset", "remove characters at offset", and "change characters at offset".  You either have to be careful with escaping delimiters, or use explicit lengths instead of simply delimiting strings.  And you also should consider that each edit might change the offset of the subsequent edits.  Technically pre-image offsets have all the information you need, but reversal of the patch is more intuitive if you also store the post-image offsets.

So given

```
well, here is the original string
```

you might have a reversible delta like

```
0/0d6:well, 14/8c12:the original1:a33/16a11: with edits
```

to yield

```
here is a string with edits
```

Of course, calculating the "most correct" patch may not be easy.

```
0/0c33:well, here is the original string27:here is a string with edits
```

would be equally valid but degenerates to the line-oriented approach.

But that's just one example; like I said, you *could* define any number of ways, depending on requirements.